# SIP over TCP versus SIP over UDP [ SIP: Session Initiation Protocol ]

Tags: tcp, network-programming, udp, sip, sip-server

**What is the difference between SIP over UDP and SIP over TCP?**

What does "SIP over TCP" really means?
Does it mean:

> both SIP and RTP use TCP

or

> SIP use TCP and RTP use UDP

Comment: This likely depends on the SIP application you are using. If you are trying to program your own SIP application, then I would suggest always using UDP for RTP, but it is not a requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"SIP over TCP" just means "send the SIP messages over a TCP stream". SIP is largely transport protocol agnostic, so the same protocol can run over SCTP, DTLS, and so on.

From the user's perspective there's no difference.

From the perspective of someone using a SIP stack/writing a SIP application, there's little difference: SIP over UDP implements various reliability mechanisms (resend+backoff for starters).

The session descriptions MAY use RTP for the media streams, but SDP is not tied to using RTP. You may use plain TCP streams if you wish, or any other protocol (provided there's a way of describing the protocol in SDP, and only useful for those clients that understand that transport protocol, of course).

RTP itself is a transport protocol that *usually* runs over UDP (because timeliness is more important in a *real-time* transport protocol than reliability), but can run over TCP (provided the media is framed - [RFC 4103](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4103) data is not, for instance).

So *usually* people will run SIP over TCP and RTP over UDP, but neither protocol is limited to this particular setup.

Comment: so then in this case(Which OP mentions of SIP over TCP...)Would RTP also be using TCP? That question is still unanswered if i understand.

Comment: @goldenmean As the answer mentioned, it depends on how the SIP application works. If you aren't sure if the SIP application is using the excepted protocol, either read the SIP application's manual or packet sniff the traffic.